# Regular Expression for Mathematic Equations in PHP

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I am trying to create a regular expression that understands mathematical equations `(>, <, =, <=, >=, !=)`. Which is something pretty simple. I have come up with:

```
/(.*)([!<>][=]|[<>=])(.*)/
```

But when I use this regex in PHP, with `preg_match`, if equation is `XYZ!=ABC`, it just matches with `=`. Shouldn't it match the first expression it found from left to right, which is currently `!=`? If mine solution is wrong -which seems so-, could anyone tell me why?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make the `(.*)` lazy; `(.*?)`, it will match the fewest possible characters before it can continue.

What you have now is greedy, so .* will match as many characters as it can to complete the expression, the longest that can match the first part is `XYZ!`, and then it needs to match the `=` in the second piece to continue.

Answer (score 0):

* is greedy(.*) first matches XYZ! the = is then matched by the second alternation of ([!<>][=]|[<>=]) so the match holds. The left most solution applies only to the expression as a whole, the rule to note here is that where greedy operators are concerned its first come first served.